# Unable to allocate memory for an array when trying to convert dict to string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, memory

I'm parsing json and building an array. I'm getting a dictionary of the json and working with it. I am taking some fields by something like that:

```
 field = response['data']['doc']['info']
```

but this is not a value of some field in json, it is a dict, I mean there is a structure like

```
field = {'id1': 0, 'name': 'some_name', 'id2': 0, 'id3': 0}
```

Then I built an array using numpy.asarray(data) and it is okey, it works fine, BUT if I'm trying to convert this dict to string with str(field) or json.dumps(field) - I am getting an error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 18.7 GiB for an array with shape (2436, 17) and data type <U121413
```

I really just dont get it. The volume of data I work with is about ~10 mb, why it says 18.7 GB? What am I missing? Appriciate any help.

Comment: Maybe it is not clear, but what I mean - that "field" I mentioned is a value of one column in array

Comment: `121413*4*2436*17` is `20G`.  Give us some info on the array, `shape` and `dtype`.  The 'U121413' dtype in the error is suspect.  It's trying to make large array containing very large strings.  Overall your problem description is incomplete, so it's impossible to say what is wrong.